# Cant debug run my Node.js and ReacJs app what wrong missing script

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio

I follow the tutorial [Create a Node.js and React app in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-nodejs-with-react-and-jsx?view=vs-2019) and when it comes to debug run I get infamous:

> The command "npm run build" exited with code 1

I see there are many question about this but nothing works for me so I also post a question. In VS Options I turn on extended verbosity diagnostic and I get this log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.13.0
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: build
4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:115:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:418:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:373:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:416:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:160:5)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:280:12
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16
4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)
5 verbose cwd L:\NetProject\NodejsWebAppBlank\NodejsWebAppBlank
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
8 verbose node v10.13.0
9 verbose npm  v6.4.1
10 error missing script: build
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any help is appreciated I think there could be some missing script

Here is package.json

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-web-app-blank",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "NodejsWebAppBlank",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": {
    "name": ""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^6.0.2",
    "typescript": "^3.5.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "webpack": "^4.33.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Kindly paste package.json too.

Comment: Thanks I added package.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This info might help

npm run build.

whenever we use run that indicate custom command.

if you don't use run that indicate general command, but in your package.json whole script section is missing.

My some project package.json

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "node scripts/start.js",
        "build": "node scripts/build.js",
        "test": "node scripts/test.js",
        "style": "styleguidist server",
        "style-build": "styleguidist build",
        "test:snapshot": "jest --config ./test/jest.config.json",
        "test:snapshot:watch": "npm run test:snapshot -- --watch"
    }
```

Comment: I stil get the , The command "npm run build" exited with code 1

Comment: if linux try --> 
sudo npm run build

Comment: And it is just personal suggestion do not use visual studio use visual code instead.
And In order to create project use npm.
I don't think you will ever face the problem.